# VS 2019 New Pull request You are not connected to a remote repository

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

In VS 2019 when I try to do "New Pull Request". I get "You are not connected to a remote repository" error.
Push, Pull, Merge and etc. work.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.7.2 and Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 16.131.28601.4

How can I solve this? What can be the reason?

Comment: In TeamExplorer --> Manage connections I have connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> VS 2019 New Pull request You are not connected to a remote repository

This is a known issue on older versions of Visual Studio. And this issue is fixed on the version `16.6 Preview 1`.

Since you are using the version `16.7.2`, please try to restart your Visual Studio and open it with administrator.

Besides, try to reconnect the git repo and on the manage connections page, expand the project/collection (grey and red icon) and select the nested project with same name (red git icon), click connect and then the 'Pull Requests' tab loaded correctly.

Check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/344645/pull-requests-in-visual-studio-you-are-not-connect.html) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After selecting select the nested project with same name (red git icon) it works

Comment: Is there a WA for older versions like `2019 16.0.0`?

Answer (score 3):

1. Click Green color 'Manage connection' icon
2. Click on 'Manage connection'
3. Drill down to your repository in the popup
4. Select the repository

[image]